# Considerations when naming a new user feature (eg. Snapchat Stories, Facebook Timeline)

Tags: user-behavior, user-centered-design, branding

With the right name, an otherwise complex web feature can be easily understood and digested by users.

Snapchat use of *Stories* to describe the idea of piecing together different snap videos to tell a story is one example. When logging into StackExchange, we have the option of using *OpenID*. Today most people in the world never pass a few hours without checking out their *Timeline*.

With the wrong name, the same feature (arguably), might fail. Does anyone bother checking out their *Circles* on Google Plus these days? What happened to Instagram *Direct*?

**In naming a new user feature, what are the factors to consider?**

Comment: Isn't one factor to just enquire what someone thinks that the term actually means? One could start, ofcourse, by trying to stay with known concepts; like you mention in your question. Interesting read: http://happyemergency.tumblr.com/post/70653086564/ux-principles-naming-features-is-like-golf-not

Comment: Thanks for sharing that article. Helpful! Definitely I would, but even asking around still doesn't seem like an accurate way to gauge how the mass market will perceive it. I think the known concepts methodology might be something. Timeline is a pretty straightforward concept that describe directly the function as it is. Stories, maybe a little. But Circles? Completely confusing, because circles PRIMARILY reference a shape in most cultures today.

Answer (score 3):

A big consideration in naming a new user feature is considering **real life idioms/metaphors** that will relate to the feature.

> Interface metaphors, such as the classic desktop metaphor common in graphical user interfaces (GUIs), leverage users’ existing knowledge of a specific domain to enhance the learnability of its software.

https://medium.com/@weareignition/why-ux-designers-should-use-idioms-rather-than-metaphors-f0e4718f4960

> 1. Metaphors Can Put Abstract Concepts in Concrete Terms
> 2. Metaphors Create Familiarity
> 3. Metaphors Can Trigger Emotions
> 4. Metaphors Can Draw the Attention of Users
> 5. Metaphors Can Motivate Users into Action

http://sixrevisions.com/user-interface/5-reasons-why-metaphors-can-improve-the-user-experience/

For all those names you mentioned the company used the real life names of the concept they were trying to portray. Facebook **Timeline** - everybody is familiar with a [timeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline) and how they display a series of events in chronological order. If they called it Facebook Feed it might take people longer to understand that concept. Google+ **Circles** is a reference to real life [social circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_circle), Snapchat Stories is immediately recognizable as a [story or report of connected events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrative)

Comment: Good answer. I think Alliteration too is widely used when naming features to make it sound catchy.

Answer (score 2):

When naming a feature, function, or anything of the sort in software, the most important thing you have to consider is clarity and cosiness. The word has to be short and understandable.

That said, naming a feature cannot be considered a success factor. It's the product itself that can conquer minds. The reason why Circles are not mainstream has less to do with the name and more with the product. Google+ in general is not doing good. It's not on a par with Facebook or Twitter.